# Test for Set Intersection Using Map Iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function to find a weak Sidon sequences (a sequence (a<sub>i</sub>) where a<sub>i</sub> + a<sub>j</sub> is different for all i < j) of arbitrary length, starting at 1.

This is what I have so far:

```
def weakSidon(sequence_length):
    """Finds a weak Sidon sequence (a sequence (a_i) of integers where a_i + a_j for i < j are all unique) of the necessary length."""
    sequence = [1]
    sums = []
    while len(sequence) < sequence_length:
        test_integer = sequence[-1] + 1
        test_sums = list(map(lambda x: test_integer + x, sequence))
        while any(x in list(test_sums) for x in sums):
            test_integer = test_integer + 1
            test_sums = list(map(lambda x: test_integer + x, sequence))
        sequence.append(test_integer)
        sums = sums + test_sums
    return sequence
```

This works (and, as I realized after doing this, just ends up being a stupid way of generating the Fibonacci sequence sans the first element), but converting the map iterator to a list and then immediately iterating over it in the generator on the next line seems silly and I'd like to know how to avoid that kludge for the future, if possible.

Any other general suggestions for simplification (particularly for that repeated `test_sums` assignment) are of course appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use set() instead of list(), for sums and test_sums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code.

The first is that you're calling `list` every time you test if a sum is within your `test_sums` list. `all(x in list(test_sums) for x in sums)` calls `list` a large number of times, and since `test_sums` is already a list, that's just wasted cycles.

The second issue is that list membership testing is slow in general, even if you're not copying the list first. It's much faster to test membership in a `set`, so you should probably use one here.

If you make `sums` a set, and change which sequence you're iterating on in your `all` call to take advantage of the fast `set.__contain__` test, you'll get something like this:

```
def weakSidon(sequence_length):
    """Finds a weak Sidon sequence (a sequence (a_i) of integers where
       a_i + a_j for i < j are all unique) of the necessary length."""
    sequence = [1]
    sums = set()                                   # start with an empty set
    while len(sequence) < sequence_length:
        test_integer = sequence[-1] + 1
        test_sums = list(map(lambda x: test_integer + x, sequence))
        while any(x in sums for x in test_sums):   # testing set membership is O(1)
            test_integer = test_integer + 1
            test_sums = list(map(lambda x: test_integer + x, sequence))
        sequence.append(test_integer)
        sums.update(test_sums)                     # update set items
    return sequence
```

You can't get rid of the one `list` call to turn the `map` generator into an actual list, because you will need to access the `test_sums` values again in the `update` step if there were no collisions.

Comment: Nitpick: I'd recommend `[x + test_integer for x in sequence]` as a more readable replacement for `list(map(lambda x: test_integer + x, sequence))`.

Comment: Looking over the documentation for sets, I see there's an isdisjoint method. Would that be a potentially more elegant solution? I assume it works similarly to the any() call here.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating `x in a` for some iterator `a` will consume some or all of `a`. And evaluating `list(a)` will consume all of `a`. In your generator `(x in list(test_sums) for x in sums)`, the expression `x in list(test_sums)` is evaluated once for every element in `sums`.

So if you didn't listify the result of `map` immediately, then your check `(x in list(test_sums) for x in sums)` wouldn't work as expected -- by the time later elements from `sums` get tested, `test_sums` has already been consumed and the expression `list(test_sums)` is `[]`. I found it helpful to check out a simpler example of this kind of situation in the interpreter.

Python actually has a built-in set data type ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)). Determining membership in a set is a constant-time operation, so if you're doing a ton of membership checks (like here) then using them is a good idea. But we can actually get rid of the `any(x in a for x in b)` construction (beautiful as it is) and just be direct, because Python also defines intersection and union on sets. If `a` and `b` are two sets, then `a | b` is their union and `a & b` is their intersection.

So your code using sets would be:

```
def weakSidon(sequence_length):
    sequence = [1]
    sums = set()
    while len(sequence) < sequence_length:
        test_integer = sequence[-1] + 1
        test_sums = {test_integer + n for n in sequence}
        while test_sums & sums:
            test_integer += 1
            test_sums = {test_integer + n for n in sequence}
        sequence.append(test_integer)
        sums |= test_sums
    return sequence
```

(the `|=` operator is to `|` what `+=` is to `+`).

I had never heard of Sidon sequences before, but I think it's really funny that the Fibonaccis turn out to be one.

Comment: Note that doing a full set intersection may be overkill when you only need to know if the intersection is non-empty. That's because it will keep testing the set items against each other even after the first overlap has been found. If you use `any`, the test will short circuit as soon as the first collision is found.

Comment: @Blckknght Good point. Also, looking at your answer makes me realize that test_sums doesn't need to be a set at all.